# app engine ndb fetch is very slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I need to store a lot of `ModelA` entities, and because app engine pricing is based on the number of entities written/read, I bundle together 100 entities and store them as one `ModelB`.

```
class ModelA(ndb.Expando):
  a1 ... a20 = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class ModelB(ndb.Model):
  data = ndb.StructuredProperty(ModelA, repeated=True)
```

I have only 80 such `ModelB` entities in my datastore, that should use around 1-2MB of memory, yet `ModelB.query().fetch()` takes 5 seconds. Is there any way to make this faster? Would using `LocalStructuredProperty` instead of `StructuredProperty` be better?

Comment: Take into account that bundling in that way might not be optimal if you then need to modify values of `ModelA`. Also, `ModelB.query().fetch()` will try to load all instances of `ModelB`, which you might want to filter out first. Maybe you can give us more details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I never want to modify the values of ModelA (they are the status of a device sampled once every minute), I only need to read them later. In my real application, modelB also contains a DateTime variable and I'm filtering on that, but the filter results might in the future get to a length of 80. It just seems strange to wait 5 seconds for 1-2mb of data representing only 80 entities.

Comment: `LocalStructuredProperty` should be better, as it is NOT indexed, and can be compressed. Anyhow, take into account that serializing/deserializing might present a performance issue if `ModelA` is a complex object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to index the values (for queries), you might want to store them as an opaque object:

```
class ModelB(ndb.Model):
    data = ndb.JsonProperty(indexed=False)

    def add_data(self, model_a)
        if not self.data:
            self.data = []
        self.data.append(model_a)
```

This will avoid the overhead of handling structured properties and validation.

Comment: Thanks, I retried using JsonProperty and it's way better.